# How to add an index that identifies and counts duplicated values?

Tags: python, pandas

With a dataframe with duplicated values for an index `ix` suxh as this:

```
   ix  value
0   1     12
1   2     14
2   2     15
3   2     12
4   3     10
5   4      9
6   5     14
7   5     21
```

How can you include a column that identifies and counts the number of duplicated values for `ix`?

#### Desired result:

```
   ix  value  dupes
0   1     12      1
1   2     14      1
2   2     15      2
3   2     12      3
4   3     10      1
5   4      9      1
6   5     14      1
7   5     21      2
```

I've tried different approaches with `pd.merge`, for example

```
pd.merge(df, df.groupby('ix').size().to_frame('dupes').reset_index(), on = 'ix', how = 'left')
```

But as you can see this will only get the total number of each duplicate:

```
   ix  value  dupes
0   1     12      1
1   2     14      3
2   2     15      3
3   2     12      3
4   3     10      1
5   4      9      1
6   5     14      2
7   5     21      2
```

Comment: `df.groupby('ix').cumcount() + 1`

Comment: ```df['dupes'] = df.groupby('ix').cumcount()+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `groupby` and then use `cumcount`

```
df['dupes'] = df.groupby('ix').cumcount().add(1)
```